# Add css attribute from a javascript variable to a html element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I stored a url in a javascript variable "bg_url" and I want to attach this url to a background-image property to a html element.

my html

```
<div id=#wrapper>
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

and my jQuery is like

```
$("#wrapper").css({ background-image: "'print(bg_url)'" });
```

but I do not get the variable attached to the css property. 
Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use camel cased property or use quotes since it contains `-` in the property name.

```
$("#wrapper").css({ backgroundImage: 'url('+ bg_url+ ')' });
// or
$("#wrapper").css({ 'background-image': 'url('+ bg_url+ ')' });
```

Although there is no need for `#` in your id attribute of the element and it's always better to use quotes to wrap the attribute value.

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

Refer : [HTML attribute with/without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056683/html-attribute-with-without-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should learn how CSS and JavaScript work. There are loads of mistakes:

1. You don't have `"`. It should be `<div id="wrapper">`. And remove the `#`.
2. You should concatenate using `+` operator.
3. Always make sure you put it inside `$(function () {})`.

Your code should be:

```js
var bg_url = "http://placehold.it/100?text=Background";
$(function () {
  $("#wrapper").css({
    backgroundImage: "url('" + bg_url + "')" // And don't forget the quotes here.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```