# Difficulties with obtaining values from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Junior Dev here. I'm trying to implement the following code in order to get all the info typed in the form and to receive an alert message ("everything is ok").

I know there is Jquery valid() function, but I have struggle with implementing it as well.So if it's possible when the textbox doesn't meet the requirements to post the error message(email needs "@", website needs "www.", name 6 letters, password="****".

Can anyone explain me with simple code how can I achieve this ?

```
<form id=registration_form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Chose Username: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form_text" id="form_username">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="error_form" id="username_error_message"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" class="form_text" id="form_password">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="error_form" id="password_error_message"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Retype Password: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" class="form_text" id="form_retype_password">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="error_form" id="retype_password_error_message"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form_text" id="form_email">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="error_form" id="email_error_message"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="sbmt_btn" value="Create Account">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: So you just need to validate the email address for an @ space?

Comment: I just need to validate that every information entered is correct and if so, to get an alert('all good')

Comment: For starters all attributes need to be wrapped in quotes, your form id isn't.  To reference with jquery for example $("#form_email").val()

Comment: Have a look at the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) it can help you validate all required inputs with minimal code. No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging me with this, I shall correct it immediately, but I doubt that would help my problem. I tried lots of, lots of different demo's, just can't validate my form correctly.

Comment: You could use type="email", couldn't you? And then you could check for jQuery('input:invalid') to have length > or = 0

Comment: Off topic:  @SPlatten they don't *need* to be wrapped in quotes at all.  More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056683/html-attribute-with-without-quotes

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes they do that's the w3c syntax.  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp , https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values

Comment: @SPlatten let me test... removes quotes from working html page... tests page... still works absolutely fine.  They're needed in some scenarios but not for *all* html and not for html5 - it's worth *recommending*, but they're not required.   More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes

Comment: Depends on which browser you are using, browsers do not always follow the standard strictly, IE for example is very loose.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). Its as simple as calling `.validate();` on your `form`

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#commentForm").validate();
  </script>
</head>
```

It covers email, required input validation and much more. Check out the docs [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

Also, using the `submitHandler` option for the plugin you can set a callback on submit if all fields are correctly validated. In the example below we use this to call `alert()` with the message *'Everythings Ok'*.

---

### Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#commentForm").validate({
    //we can use the handler to check if form is correctly validated
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('Everythings Ok');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[class="error"], textarea[class="error"] {
  border: 1px solid #f00 !important;
}

.error{
  margin: 5px;
  color: #f00 !important;
}

/* To cover your additional requirement mentioned in the comments */
body { 
 background: lightblue url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/winter_background_311052.jpg) no-repeat fixed center; 
}

/* For your additional requirement */
form {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Doing this with jQuery would require a lot of different validation techniques most likely including other libraries like Regex. The plugin aggregates all of them into one plugin that can be reused across multiple pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed code explanation. As I have done everything as you've written and checked the docs as well, I'm currently unavailable of receiving the error messages at all. Any tips of what might have gone wrong ?

Comment: @NikolaStoilov Sure, you can call it wherever you want so long as its wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` function and enclosed in `<script>` tags. Or you could place all of your JS in an external file and include a reference to it on each of your html pages, id recommend that for code reuse.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm currently doing it as a hobby. So correct me if I'm wrong but:

In the <head> i put the <script src >for jquery,jquery-validation-form then in the body is my form, and below I should have enclosed in <SCRIPT> the document.ready and validate code you've written ?

Comment: The general conception is that it should be in the `<head>` tags enclosed within `<script>` tags but can also be added to the `<body>` tag towards the bottom. Ill update the answer to make more sense

Comment: I'm trying as well to make a transparent background colour underneath the form so there could be contrast between the text and the background-image of <body> when I apply to the css:

`form {
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.3;
}`

When i do that, it makes the inputs and text to opacity 0.3 as well. Any Idea ? :/

Comment: @NikolaStoilov Try: `form {
  background-color: transparent;
}` Example has been updated

Comment: I actually achieved it with giving an rgba property with 0.3 opacity --> 
`rgba(63,191,191,0.3);`

Thank you once again !