# Different delimiters to seperate attributes in HTML tags

Tags: html, firefox

What are different delimiters used to separate HTML attributes when spaces,double quotes,single quote are not allowed

Comment: Under what circumstances are spaces, double and single quotes not allowed?

Comment: As a security concern, to avoid XSS attacks

Comment: Interesting. I don't know enough to comment further.  I did find https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet though.  Good luck

Answer (score -1):

> By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39). [[w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)

HTML attributes follow the SGML definition of attributes, therefore you cannot have a HTML attribute without these characters. If `"` and `'` are not allowed then you cannot write valid HTML.

Comment: That's incorrect on both accounts. The W3C text you cited is simply wrong. SGML has always allowed omitting LIT and LITA characters (= the double and single quotation marks in the reference concrete syntax) on *declared* attributes, and moreover allows omitting quotes even on undeclared attributes subject to the `FEATURES MINIMIZE ATTRIB OMITNAME` SGML declaration setting. HTML5 allows omitting quotes on any attribute as long as the value doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: See https;//www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-sgml-xml.html and http;//sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html#unquoted-attribute-values (my site)

Comment: My apologies, [you are correct ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056683/html-attribute-with-without-quotes#comment65290394_13056720). However, as OP's question mentions that spaces are not allowed either, they could still surely not have valid HTML.