# React TSX tag params with quotes

Tags: html, reactjs, parameters, tags, tsx

Is there any advantage of using single quotation marks over double quotation marks in TSX HTML tags?

Single quotation marks:

```
<Table aria-label='simple table'>
  ...
</Table>
```

Double quotation marks:

```
<Table aria-label="simple table">
  ...
</Table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2):

> By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks can be included within the attribute value when the value is delimited by double quote marks, and vice versa. Authors may also use numeric character references to represent double quotes (") and single quotes ('). For double quotes authors can also use the character entity reference ".

so it does not matter, choose whatever style you like

Comment: While your answer is helpful, the reason why one would use single quotes instead of the more common double quotes as attribute value delimiter (apart from personal preference) is that it allows the double quote character itself as part of the attribute value. Also, the text on w3.org is neither entirely correct (see <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083218/different-delimiters-to-seperate-attributes-in-html-tags/56109294#comment98853098_56109294>) nor should it be cited as a reference for SGML (which is an ISO not W3C standard) nor for JSX.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is use `.prettierrc`

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false
}
```