# Vue-Cli: why after the build the index.html is not generated with quotes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

After running the npm build, the `./dist/index.html` file is generated without the quotes. The project does not have a *webpack.config.js* or a *vue.config.js*. The build is generated from the example project made with `vue create`. How do I solve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel=icon href=/favicon.ico><title>html-project</title><link href=/app.css rel=preload as=style><link href=/app.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/chunk-vendors.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/app.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but html-project doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id=app></div><script src=/chunk-vendors.js></script><script src=/app.js></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute quotes aren't necessary there (that's still [valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13058319/6277151)), so they're removed in production builds to reduce the output size of the HTML file.

If you prefer to keep the quotes, you could configure the [HTML minifier options](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference) (i.e., specifically `removeAttributeQuotes`) as follows:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('html').tap((args) => {
      args[0].minify = {
        ...args[0].minify,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false
      }
      return args
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a valid html that does not work. If the html is opened in the browser, the blank page is returned. But thanks for the answer, although I had already solved it using removeAttributeQuotes in the same way.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an example where this fails?