# VueJS - prod build removes attribute quotes from HTML

Tags: vue.js, webpack

First, is it standard to remove attribute quotes from HTML in a minified production build? It seems like that would cause problems in some browsers / platforms? If so, then everything below doesn't really matter, but I'm still curious.

I have the below in my `vue.config.js` and it works to keep attribute quotes in the prod build, but breaks yarn serve.

Local Vue version 2.6.12. @vue/cli version 4.5.4.

```
  chainWebpack: (config) => { // chainWebpack grayed out
    config.plugin("html").tap((args) => {
      args[0].minify.removeAttributeQuotes = false;
      return args;
    });
  },
```

It doesn't seem to find `minify` - I keep getting: `ERROR  TypeError: Cannot set property 'removeAttributeQuotes' of undefined`

Comment: This is blind shot from me. What if you try using something similar to here?: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/enable-minify-removeattributequotes/47431/4

Answer (score 1):

> First, is it standard to remove attribute quotes from HTML in a minified production build?

It's not standard but still [valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13058319/6456166). The attribute quotes are removed in production builds to reduce the output size of the HTML size so if you're en DEV environment (like when you're running `yarn serve`) the object `args[0].minify` is `undefined`.

So for keeping the quotes in production build and not get errors in other environments, you can set the attribute `removeAttributeQuotes` as follows (instead of modifying its value, like in your code):

```js
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin('html').tap((args) => {
      args[0].minify = {
        ...args[0].minify,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false,
      }
      return args
    })
  },
```

[See related issue](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/needs-quotes-for-attributes/41998)