# Django/HTML - HTML not showing complete string from the context, rather only part of it

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, jinja2

I am working on a Django site. This site has a form with preview button.

How I would like it to work:
Text entered in the input field on HTML. Preview button pressed. Python script runs in background. Form to retain it's values.

What I have done:
So far I have managed to a create form, a preview button, run the script and return the values as context to HTML and show it on the form.
However the problem is, if the string has spaces. Form only shows first section of the string rather than whole string.
Example: If I enter name as "John Smith" and press preview button. Form only shows me "John". Same if I do "London, United Kingdom". It shows me "London,"

I have looked onto Google and stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution to this, hence thought to ask here. I would appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

views.py

```
   '''
   nname = request.POST['name']
   django_run_script()
   context = {'name': nname}
   '''
```

index.html

```
'''
<div class="form-group">
<label class="label" for="name">Full Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required value={{ name|default:"" }}>
</div>
'''
```

Thank you,
Kind regards,

Shashank

Edit1:
Views.py

```
# # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
# """
# Copyright (c) 2019 - present AppSeed.us
# """

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.conf import settings

from django import template

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app.script import django_run_script

def index(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method=='POST' and 'preview' in request.POST:
        nname = request.POST['name']
        location = request.POST['location']

        django_run_script(nname)

        print(nname, location)
        context = {
            'name': nname,
            'location': location,
        }

        return render(request, 'index.html', context)

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

models.py

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (c) 2019 - present AppSeed.us
"""

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/assets/css/style.css">


    </head>
    <body>
                    


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="row no-gutters mb-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="contact-wrap w-100 p-md-5 p-4">
                                <form action="" method="POST" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" class="contactForm">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="label" for="name">Full Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required value={{ name|default:"" }}>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="col-md-12"> 
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="label" for="name">Select location</label>
                                                {% comment %} <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Location"> {% endcomment %}
                                                <input class="form-control" name="location" id="location" type="text" placeholder="Enter your current location" type="text" autocomplete="on" runat="server" required value={{ location|default:"" }}>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="col-md-12" hidden> 
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="label" for="city">Auto Location</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="city" required value={{ city|default:"" }}>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="preview" type="submit" value="Preview" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                                <div class="submitting"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="contact100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                                {% comment %} <img src="/static/assets/images/img-01.png" alt="IMG"> {% endcomment %}
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="col-md-5 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="contact100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                            <img src="/static/assets/images/NameNatal380.png" alt="IMG">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="static/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/assets/js/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="static/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/assets/js/google-map.js"></script>
  <script src="static/assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="static/assets/vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $('.js-tilt').tilt({
            scale: 1.1
        })
    </script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I enter name as "John Smith" and press preview button. Form only shows me "John". Same if I do can you show the code where you have implemented this share complete views.py and models

Comment: @sarangkkl I have added the info as per your request. Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: can you explain what django_run_script doing here

Comment: It doesn't do anything at the moment. Currently I have pass in the function.

Comment: what you are telling is weired for me i use       nname = request.POST.get['name']
        location = request.POST.get['location'] and i will get everything what user type just try this if it work if yes i will write the answer

Comment: I get error 
TypeError at /
'method' object is not subscriptable

. When I print in python. I get full John Smith and London, United Kingdom. But on the form I only get "John" and "London,"

Comment: did you try request.post.get

Comment: When I try request.POST.get['name'] I get 'method' object is not subscriptable.
When I try request.post.get['name'] I get 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'.
When I try request.POST.get('name') I get same issue what I was getting above. The value of field only shows first section of string and does't not show Smith, if I enter John Smith.

Comment: lets meet on google meet i want to see in person your issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML attribute with/without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056683/html-attribute-with-without-quotes)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat May I know why you have removed the solution I added previously and then asking me above question after that?

Comment: @isash questions are supposed to be _separate_ from answers, please don't edit your question and put the answer there and also adding that "_closed_" in the title. My previous comment is an auto generated comment by voting to close your question as a duplicate, you can accept that closure if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I think I have managed to figure out the solution to this issue. I had to make a minor change. See codes below:

From:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required value={{ name|default:"" }}>
```

To:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required value="{{ name|default:"" }}">
```